# What is the actual use of categories instead of inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to understand the actual use of categories as opposed to inheritance in Objective-C. When should I prefer to use a category? A real-life example with code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used categories when I need to add some convenient functions that I will use repeatedly to the existing class without having a need to subclass to overwrite some existing functions of that class.

For example, when I want to check for an empty string, or remove all leading and trailing spaces of a string:

.h file:

```
@interface NSString  (Extension)

-(BOOL)isEmptyString;
-(NSString *)trimLeadingAndTrailingWhiteSpaces;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation NSString  (Extension)

-(BOOL)isEmptyString
{
    NSString *myString = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if (myString.length == 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
       return FALSE;
}

-(NSString *)trimLeadingAndTrailingWhiteSpaces
{
    NSString *myString = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    return myString;
}
@end
```

To use it:

```
 someString = [someString trimLeadingAndTrailingWhiteSpaces];

 if ([someString isEmptyString])
       {
         //someString is empty, do whatever!
       }
```

Comment: In obj-c you should use YES/NO and not TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: In this case, it should be `return (myString.length == 0)` anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

When you need to add functionality to an existing class.

For example, your app is working with `NSDate` or `NSString` instances and you want to add some functionality. You cannot add the functionality to a subclass because you can't force system methods to return the subclass.

Just look into the examples in the API:

1/ NSDictionary is used to hold file attributes and has a method that returns file size.
2/ `NSString` has a UI category that extends it with drawing. Note that you don't want a separate subclass of string that can be drawn. You want all strings to have the ability to be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

I see categories as a sort of easier way of achieving some of the functionality provided by inheritance. There are other things categories do which are not provided by inheritance. Categories allow you to extend the functionality of a existing class without subclassing them. You can also use them to replace existing methods in classes. A category method is sort of bolted onto the existing class unlike a subclass which direct descendant of the original class. Once category method is added to a objective c class it is available to all instances of the class including the ones not created by you.

For example , if you have to encryption function which you need to use on all data in your project and say most your data uses only NString for saving and manipulation. One of the ways you can go about it is to create a category for NSString

NSString-Encryption.h

```
   @interface NSString (Encryption)
     -(NSString*) encrypt;
    @end
```

NSString-Encryption.m

```
#import "NSString-Encryption.h"
@implementation NSString (Encryption)
 -(NSString*) encrypt
{ 
 // your encryption method here 
  return encryptedString; 
}
@end
```

UseNSString-encryption.m

```
 NSString *testString = @"this is test"; 
 NSString *encryptedString = [testString encrypt];
```

As you can see that the category is easier to use than subclass. This method can be called from NSMutableString also as it inherits from NSString. So it is powerful.

You can also use category to replace existing methods on classes.

Another use of a category is that it can be used for **private methods** as objective c does not have a formal private designation for methods. This done by putting a category in a .m file instead of .h file.

Phone.h

```
@interface Phone:NSObject
 -(void) call; 
 @end
```

Phone.m

```
   @interface Phone(Private)
       -(void) validatePhoneEntry:(NSString*) phoneNumber; 
     @end 

     @implementation Phone 

     -(void) validatePhoneEntry:(NSString*) phoneNumber
     {

     } 

     -(void) call
     {
     }

     @end
```

The disadvantage of categories is that you cant use them if you need to add member variable to classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sulthan explains it well.  Here is a code [example](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) of extending the functionality of NSString by adding a category.  You can use categories this way to extend classes that you don't have the implementations for without subclassing them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *add methods* to a class, use a category. If you want to *change functionality* of existing methods in a class, create a subclass.

It's kinda/sorta possible to use a category to replace an existing method, sort of like overriding in a subclass, but you shouldn't use categories for this. There are three reasons: 1) you lose access to the original method; 2) you won't break existing code; 3) if more than one category attempts to "override" the same method, the method that the class will end up with is undefined. Basically, the class will end up with the method from the last category applied to the class, but the order in which categories are applied can't be relied on. It's a recipe for a mess, so just don't do it.

So, you could use a category to add methods to NSData such as `+(NSData*)dataWithCryptographicallyRandomBytes:(NSUInteger)length` or `-(void)base64Decode`. But if you wanted to change the behavior of an existing method, like `-writeToFile:atomically:`, you should create a subclass of NSData and implement your new functionality there. For one thing, you might still want to use the existing behavior in your override, and subclassing lets you do that by calling `[super writeToFile:file atmoically:YES]`. Also, using a subclass here means that your new behavior will only affect your own code -- it won't affect uses of NSData elsewhere in the framework that may not expect your new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are similar to Java interfaces (in java the implementation is not optional) -  a way to group methods and make objects respond to a particular API - independent of the class type. Inheritance makes sense if you need to add additional ivars and the new class matches a isa relation (student isa person). Adding a few utility methods does not make an isa case - this is usualy done with protocols. Categories are often used with delegates where the methods in question are optional.