# What is difference between inheritance and category

Tags: objective-c

what is the difference between inheritance and category in objective-c

Both are used  for the subclass! So what is difference between them

Comment: [There are at least a few](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+inheritance+category) existing questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522341/difference-between-inheritance-and-categories-in-objective-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343670/what-is-the-actual-use-of-categories-instead-of-inheritance as well as the docs, which would answer this for you.

Answer (score 7):

While Category is a nice way to add functionality to the base class, people like me who come from other object oriented technology such as Flash, will find a little difficult to understand as to how this thing relates to the inheritance chain. The same question came up to my mind and I did a quick research on the topic.

The final thing is Category does the same thing as it tells about itself. It adds functionality to the base class. If you remember this, then there would be no confusion at all.

Well, for that to understand, lets take an example. Suppose there is a Class A and Class B is a subclass of Class A. In the application Class B is used in a lot of places. Now, there is a need to add some more functionality to Class A, so a new category is written as "A+newRole". Once this category is written, the new functionality is added to the base class and in this case, Class A. That means, all those classes which are child classes of Class A such as Class B, automatically gets the functionality. Thats freaking cool. One can straight away go ahead and call the new methods added in the Category from the child classes. The only thing necessary here is to import the Category file to the appropriate place.

Comment: Ok great. what about subclassing and category?

Answer (score 4):

A category adds extra functionality to a class without generating a new class at all, you just extend it but it does not have polimorphism implied or anyting like it.

Inheritance on the other hand, generates a new class on its own right in which you can add new instance variables and override behavior from the parent class by polimorphism.

Comment: I would also add that in a category, you cannot add instance variables, whereas in a subclass you can.